# ubuntu 14.04 logs out randomly

Tags: drivers, logout

After installing new graphic card (Radeon HD 3450) Ubuntu 14.04 keeps logging out randomly, for example it logs out when I use the command :
`unity --replace && setsid unity`
I tried installing the propitiatory driver but it crashed my unity desktop and my system was running in command line mode so I had to reinstall the system.

Comment: That's not a 'random logout'. That's an X Server crash. Crashes have potential for data loss.